# django cannot create model with sufficient data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**models.py**

```
class QuestionReply(models.Model):
    reply_user = models.ForeignKey(cUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reply_question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reply = models.TextField()

    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class AddQuestionReply(APIView):
    def post(self, request, id):
        try:
            reply = request.data.get('reply')
            reply_user = request.data.get('reply_user')

            reply_to_question = models.QuestionReply(reply_user=reply_user, reply_question=id, reply=reply)
            reply_to_question.save()

            return Response({'OK': 'Reply added'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except:
            return Response({'400': f'QuestionReply has invalid data'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('questions/question-reply/add/<int:id>', views.AddQuestionReply.as_view(), name='add-question-reply')
```

**data sent**

```
{
    "reply_user": "1",
    "reply": "Hello, world"
}
```

I have a model with 2 foreign keys, a TextField and 2 default fields, I sent the needed data to the url(reply_question comes from the url) but for some reason the model doesnt get created and an error occurs.

Comment: Please share the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `id` and `reply_user` are both `ForeignKey`s, you should work with `reply_user_id` and `reply_question_id` to specify the primary keys of the corresponding objects, so:

```
reply_to_question = QuestionReply.objects.create(
    reply_user_id=reply_user,
    reply_question_id=id,
    reply=reply
)
```